# Do a post callout and get the location header from rest service class

Tags: apex, rest, post, rest-service

I have a requirement and I am not sure is it possible or not. My requirement is that I have a rest service class with @httpGet annotation where I am getting Id of a record after that I need to do rest post callout with that Id in the same transaction and that callout returns a location header which I need to use to create a response for rest service class.
Any suggestion will be help very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for HttpResponse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm), you'll see that there are two methods that should interest you: `getHeader()`, and `getHeaderKeys()`.

`getHeaderKeys()` gives you a list of strings. If a "location" header is given to you in the response, then it'll be one of the entries in that list. After confirming its existence, you could then call `getHeader()`.

Your `@RestResource` class has access to the response that Salesforce will return to the caller of your apex REST class via `RestContext.response`, which is an instance of the [`RestResponse` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm). It has a public `headers` variable which is a `Map<String, String>` which you can add things to (such as your "location" header from the other callout).